# JBoss EAP 6.4 log par application

Tags: logging, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8, wildfly-10

I'm running a stadalone JBoss EAP 6.4  in a cluster. I would have log file per application.

I added in application Manifest `Logging-Profile: das-log-profile` and  I have this in standalone-ha.xml:
{code}

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.5">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.security">
            <level name="TRACE"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <logging-profiles>
            <logging-profile name="das-log-profile">
                <file-handler name="das-log-handler" autoflush="true">
                    <level name="TRACE"/>
                    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="das.log"/>                        
                </file-handler>
                <logger category="ca.qc.gouv.msp.das" use-parent-handlers="false">
                    <level name="TRACE"/>
                    <handlers>
                        <handler name="das-log-handler"/>
                    </handlers>
                </logger>
            </logging-profile>
        </logging-profiles>
    </subsystem>
```

{code}

What is wrong? There is no records in log file das.log
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Everything looks okay in the configuration. Is this an EAR or a WAR?

Comment: The application has .ear(EJB/JPA) and .war(JSF/Richfaces).   A das.log file is created, but there is no log records

Comment: Try turning on trace logging for `org.jboss.as.logging` (/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as.logging:add(level=TRACE)). It should log some messages about finding the profile I believe.

Comment: I turned on trace logging for org.jboss.as.logging (/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as.logging:add(level=TR‌​ACE))  but the still no log records in das.log.

Comment: Sorry the message I was referring to should be in the `server.log`. You should see something like "Registering log context...".

Comment: Yes James. I see in server.log "Registering log context ....for profile 'das-log-profile',  but the still no log records in das.log

Comment: Okay that's good then. What logging framework are you using?

Comment: We use JDK   java.util.logging

Comment: In our application, We use JDK java.util.logging. We don't use Lo4J or other frameworks

Comment: Try putting the handler on the root logger then. `/subsystem=logging/logging-profile=das-log-profile/root-logger=ROOT:add(level=INFO, handlers=[das-log-handler])`

Comment: Still no log records in `das.log.`

Comment: That is really odd. What happens if you remove the profile from the deployment? Maybe some dependency is doing something to the `LogManager`.

Comment: Now it works. It was my mistakes in name of profile in my MANIFESTfile.